# ExpressJS: Redirect to an URL handled by client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using ExpressJs for backend and ReactJS for frontend. The server is running on localhost:3000, the client is runnning on localhost:8080. I want to redirect user to Chat page after they have successfully logged in. So I have the code in server:

```
(req, res) => {
  //doing some authenticate actions up here
  if (/*successful*/) {
    //some actions here
    res.redirect("/chat");
  }

  //actions on failure down here
};
```

But after logging in to the account, I get this error

`GET http://localhost:8080/chat 404 (Not Found)`

The `http://localhost:8080/chat` is exists and it is handled by client-side, if I type it in address bar and go, I still can access the Chat page.

I also have the code that handles any request not matching server routes, so that request can be sent to client for handling:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/dist/index.html"));
});
```

What is wrong with my code? Did I miss something?

Comment: BTW you can also do that on client side like on success of API call check status code or condition and redirect to your view.
........
renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/target' />
    }
  }

.....   Like : <Redirect to='/target' /> This will also prevent your app from reloading.

Comment: Yeah, at first, I did that. But I think it will be better if that job is handled by server

Comment: When you use `app.get("*", (req, res) => {` you must change way to serve static files (to math some path).

Comment: Have you applied auth on client side routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect the user after a successful response from the API. It is not better handled by the back-end because you have a single page application, which technically has no additional pages that the server is aware of, which is why you are getting the 404 error when trying to redirect to `http://localhost:8080/chat`. It is only aware of your `index.html` file which serves your bundles react code. The reason you are able to type in `/chat` into the address bar is because your UI is set up to handle requests from the router you are using. It is not the server directing you there.

It should be simple, here's an example:

```
logUserIn = async (userData) => {
  const isAuthed = await authenticateUser(userData)
  if (isAuthed) {
    this.props.history.push('/chat');
  } else {
    console.log('User not found!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, know I understand. At first, I did that on client (redirect the user after a successful response from the API), but I thought it would be better if it was handled by the server. Thank you for your help!